# How to show javascript alert via Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

I want to show alert after the user successfully logs in and call some other javascript function.

Like we do it in .NET and it shows javascript alert if the condition is true

```
if (SOME_CONDITION) {
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "alert('Hello')", true);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your code. Show us what you tried. Create a minimal reproducible example. Your question will be removed if it does not comply with our rules. Consider reading this: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have not tried yet and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service, and the people volunteering their time here would appreciate if you put in some effort to figure it out yourself by looking for resources on SO and elsewhere before posting a question here. Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [help/on-topic], and provide a [mre]. _Specific_ questions about your code are allowed, but "do this for me" is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a template and pass either a 0 or 1, 0 for no alert, 1 for a alert.

This is the python code:

```
def playAlert():
    return render_to_string("alert.html", {"alert": 1})
```

This is the template:

```
{% if alert == 1 %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Logged In")
</script>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I am using Django Framework and there is no render_template function